# i was trying to use google distance matrix but I'm getting "status": "INVALID_REQUEST"

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-maps-api-3

```
const GOOGLE_API_KEY = "API_Key"

 useEffect(() => {
    if (!origin || !destination) return;
    const getTravelTime = async () => {
      fetch(
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json? 
          units=imperial&origins=${origin.description}&destinations
          ${destination.description}&key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
    };

    getTravelTime();
  }, [origin, destination, GOOGLE_API_KEY]);
```

here's my consle log {"destination_addresses": [], "origin_addresses": [], "rows": [], "status": "INVALID_REQUEST"}

Comment: Did you try the [example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/start)?  `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=New%20York%20City%2C%20NY&origins=Washington%2C%20DC&units=imperial&key=YOUR_API_KEY`

Comment: yes , this's one is working, Thank you!

Comment: So is that all you needed? Are we done here?  Perhaps you're not escaping special characters in your `origin.description` or `destination.description` for the URL properly?  perhaps `encodeURIComponent` is needed? I can't tell from your last comment if there's still an issue.

Comment: i have fixed the problem was in the url. here's my code ,                                                                 ```const getTravelTime = async () => {
      fetch(
        `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?destinations=${destination.description}&origins=${origin.description}&units=imperial&key=${GOOGLE_API_KEY}`
      )
        .then((res) => res.json())
        .then((data) => {
          console.log(data);
        });
    };```